# ScheduledRedelivery combined Retry not redelivering to RabbitMq

Tags: masstransit

I'm using [masstransit/rabbitmq](https://hub.docker.com/r/masstransit/rabbitmq) docker image - RabbitMQ with the delayed exchange.

I have added the following lines into my configuration:

[RabbitMq scheduler configured](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/rabbitmq-delayed.html)-

```
x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
```

Endpoint Redelivery [Configuration](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery)-

```
e.UseScheduledRedelivery(...);

e.UseMessageRetry(...);
```

MessageRetry is working as expected. I was also expecting the messages would be redelivered to the queue again after each interval specified in UseScheduledRedelivery. But no event fired at all and seems UseScheduledRedelivery not working in this configuration.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: [Repost](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2522) from GitHub Discussions.

Comment: [Repost](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2522#discussioncomment-773448) from GitHub Discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue in MassTransit, related to redelivering messages from *batch* consumers only. It was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/commit/e5e6f7f81b72dc1929dfdfff9b208059b3976eb9).